# content and fields won't show up on new single

Tags: templating, field, navigation, singles, content

I just installed Craft, linked it to my database (localhost) and then created a new single "about" page. But when I go to edit the single, there are no fields. I haven't changed anything else! When I go to the slug it shows the right template, but there's no content to pull in, since I can't add it in with the dashboard. I've enabled Dev Mode and there are no error logging. Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed it! Had to do with the ordering of things when editing the entry type

Comment: Would you mind posting an official answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it... I hadn't assigned a field to the section.